# Can't install linux-image-extra and openjdk-9-jdk

Tags: linux-headers

I'm trying to install **openjdk-9-jdk**. I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-9-jdk : Depends: openjdk-9-jre (= 9~b114-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: openjdk-9-jdk-headless (= 9~b114-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running "sudo apt-get -f install" results in this error:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 150 not upgraded.
57 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 165 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 227285 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: It says: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb` so I would try: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic_4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1_amd64.deb` and try again `sudo apt-get -f install`